# User generated review site where users are matched when they review products similarly

Tags: rating

On my site users will be able to give a 1 to 5 rating for various different products. I want to show users other users that have rated products in a similar way.

So in simplistic terms, if the followong users rated a prodcut like so:

User A - 5 stars
User B - 4 stars
User C - 1 stars
User D - 0 stars

Then User A and User B would be matched, and User C and User D would also be matched.

How sophisticated an algorithm is achievable with only drupal modules and minimal php? Ideally a point system would find the similarity / difference between users’ ratings for all the products that they have both rated, and then find the top 5 closest matches and rank them accordingly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module looks like it would do the trick.
http://drupal.org/project/fivestar_rec

Details from its project page:

> This module makes content recommendations based on users Fivestar votes. It provides two types of recommendations:
>
> - "Users who liked this also liked": Shows a list of nodes on a node's page. Recommendations are computed based on whether the the nodes received similar Fivestar ratings from users.
> - "Recommendations for you": Shows a list of recommended nodes to the current user based on the user's previous ratings. This is personalized recommendations to each particular user.
>
> The recommendations are provided with the Views module and are fully customizable.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable using some combination of [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag), [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar), and [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views). You can use Views to find users that match criteria based on the current user. You shouldn't need *any* PHP, in theory at least.

Comment: Im not sure I need Flag. I was going to use Fivestar which uses the Voting API. How would I use Views for this? I know Views can do stuff like finding users with the same role, but can it do more complicated algorithm type stuff? Thanks